# fadeIn fadeOut JQuery add and remove class issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, fadein, fadeout

I'm attempting to make a form sticky sidebar on my Squarespace website. This is the JQuery I'm using to achieve the sticky sidebar. I'm trying to create a fade in effect when the form attaches to the scrolling and fade out effect right before the form touches the footer (and vice versa for scrolling up).

Here is my JQuery script:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
jQuery("document").ready(function($){
var nav = $('form');
var footerTop = $('footer').offset().top;
var navHeight = $('#form').outerHeight();
var stopPoint = footerTop - navHeight - 70;
 $(window).scroll(function () {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 450) {
      nav.addClass("form-fixed");
   } else {
      nav.removeClass("form-fixed");
  }
   if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 2740) {
      nav.addClass("form-stop");
   } else {
      nav.removeClass("form-stop");
   }
  });
 });
</script>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
/*Home V2*/
.form
  {posiiton: relative;}


.form-fixed 
  {position: fixed; 
   background-color: #F5FFFB; 
   top: 80px;
   right: 7%;
   z-index: 9999;
   width: 20%;}

.form-stop
  {position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   top: auto;
   left: 0;}
```

I've been trying to attach .fadeIn() or .fadeOut() at the ends of the add/remove class commands. It works, but it's either only complicit during one command or fading in and out repeatedly. Any help?

Comment: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` - update your jquery plz.

Comment: Could you explain what is happening with it fading in and out repeatedly? This could be due to a breakpoint issue on `scrollTop()`

Comment: @OliverHeward Thank you! As I'm scrolling up and down the page, it will fade out and back in before hitting the 450 top point and 2740 bottom. What's happening is that it fades out as quickly as it fades in. Does that explain it better?

Comment: You can set timing within `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()`. From memory there are preset values for `fadeOut('slow') fadeOut('fast')`, but it works on a `ms` basis like most of javascript. So you can set `fadeOut('1500')` and `fadeIn('500')` so that it leaves the screen slower and fades in faster.

Comment: I would suggest having a look at these two links https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/ && https://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/ for more info on the functions.

Comment: @OliverHeward Sorry, I should've been clearer. The issue isn't the pacing of the fadeIn and fadeOut. It's that it's blinking instead of remaining static in between the beginning and ending points established. I also can't for the life of me get it to fade out at the 2740 ending point.

Comment: Could you drop your code into a codepen or sandbox so I can take a look?